# HOW to inspect MacOS native application

Tags: xcode, appium, ui-automation

How to inspect MacOS native application? Appium? Xcode?
I have tried Appium, but looks like it works for IOS app only?

For example, I want to locate the URL box in Safari.
So that I can get the url from atomac.

Answer (score 6):

There's a separate project "appium-for-mac", which you can use to automate macOS applications: https://github.com/appium/appium-for-mac

To inspect macOS apps, it seems the recommended tool would be Xcode's Accessibility Inspector (Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Accessibility Inspector)

[image: Accessibility Inspector]